# MS Access 2002 / MS SQL 2008 R2 - Problems deleting records based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2002

I'm trying to get my code to delete records from an access 2002 database table that is linked to an MS Sql 2008 database table through a form event.  I just want it to delete all records where User is null and Date is null.

Here's the snippet that's giving me trouble:

```
Dim delSQL As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
delSQL = "DELETE * FROM Notifications WHERE User IsNull;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(delSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

DoCmd.RunSQL delSQL
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I honestly don't know why this isn't working.  I ran the SQL statement above (not including the Date part as I wanted to get the User criteria working first) on the SQL server side and it works.  But every time I try to get it to run in VBA for Access 2002, I get an error when it goes to execute the SQL.

Comment: `IS NULL` not `ISNULL` and remove `*`

Comment: Done and still not working. I'm still getting an Invalid Operation error.

Comment: Is this question still unresolved?  If so, please help us understand what more you need. Thanks.

Comment: Hi HansUp, you answered this question a while ago (see the post you made before on July 17th)

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a reserved word.  Either enclose it in square brackets, or qualify the field name with the table name or alias.

`IsNull` is a function.  Either use `Is Null` as @AlexK. suggested or use the field name as the argument to `IsNull()`.

The `*` in `DELETE *` is not required.  Access will not throw an error if you include it.  And it can be useful when you wish to preview the affected rows in the Access query designer's Datasheet View.

```
delSQL = "DELETE * FROM Notifications AS n WHERE n.User Is Null"
```

I suggest you leave `SetWarnings` on, and use `CurrentDb.Execute` with *dbFailOnError* to execute the `DELETE`.  Since the data source is a linked SQL Server table, also include *dbSeeChanges*:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
CurrentDb.Execute delSQL, dbSeeChanges + dbFailOnError
```

That approach will give you better information about any problems encountered.

Comment: Tried this, but still getting an error. I changed the field name from user to KUser. Came back with a Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'n.KUser IsNull'

Comment: Ok, it's coming back saying with an error saying I must use dbSeeChangers option when I use this

Comment: Still no dice.  This is really bizarre. It should be working

Comment: It's Working! I had left my rst.close in there and it was throwing a fit. HUGE thanks HansUp! I'm using a comma